# Application crash while using a custom method accepting block as input parameter

Tags: cocoa, objective-c-blocks

I am trying to make a method in a category of NSArray class and use it, which tests every object (string) in an array and returns an array containing the first object which passes the test.

Here is the method which I defined:

```
- (NSArray *)objectsPassingTest:(BOOL(^)(id obj, BOOL *stop))predicate
{
    NSMutableArray *outputArray = [NSMutableArray array];


    for (id obj in self)
    {
        BOOL *stop;

        if (predicate(obj,stop)) {
            [outputArray addObject:obj];
        }

        if (stop) {
            break;
        }
    }

    return [NSArray arrayWithArray:outputArray];
}
```

And here is the code snippet where I used it:

```
NSArray *inputArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Objective - C", @"is", @"fun", nil];

NSArray *outputArray = [inputArray objectsPassingTest:^BOOL(id obj, BOOL *stop) {

                if ([obj length] > 2) {
                    *stop = YES;
                    return YES;
                }
                else
                {
                    return NO;
                }

}];

NSLog(@"outputArray - %@",outputArray);
```

Problem is - after displaying correct output, Objective -c in this case, application crashes.

Can anyone suggest me if I am doing it wrong some where ?

Comment: Are you aware that `NSArray` already defines `indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:`?

Comment: yes Rob... I am trying to understand implementation of methods which take block as input parameter... and above method I took only as an example:)

Answer (score 0):

If you wan't to implement something like the passing test functionality you can use a pointer to an BOOL (because BOOL is defined as "typedef signed char BOOL")

But you set `*stop = YES` in your block on an not initialized `BOOL` pointer, which let your app crashing.
One solution is to set an initialize BOOL value:

```
    BOOL test = NO;
    BOOL *stop = &test;
```

A good guide to blocks is here: http://cocoasamurai.blogspot.de/2009/09/guide-to-blocks-grand-central-dispatch.html

Comment: hi x2on ... thnx for your quick reply... one more question... can you suggest me how apple guys would have implemented this method:- (NSIndexSet *)indexesOfObjectsAtIndexes:(NSIndexSet *)indexSet options:(NSEnumerationOptions)opts passingTest:(BOOL (^)(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop))predicate ... note they are passing BOOL *stop as input parameter to predicate block